# Subiquity keeps crashing when attempting to install Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell PowerEdge R320

Tags: server, system-installation, raid

I have an old Dell PowerEdge R320 that I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on. I do realize, that this is rather old hardware and bound to create problems with newer software.

When I start booting into the Stick and select the `Try to Install Ubuntu Server` option, I get the error message `error: you need to load the kernel first.`. Because of that I chose the `Ubuntu Server with the HWE kernel` option, just to see if it would work.

It did start Subiquity and I could perform the first few setup steps, as soon as I chose an install type, however, Subiquity crashed. In the crash log, I found two different errors:

`mount: /tmp/tmps52gkxfr/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs.dir: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` in the `server_request_fail.crash` file and `ServerDisconnectedError` in the `ui.crash` file respectively.

I couldn't find any results that matched my problems regarding these error messages.

I want to use a RAID10 of 4 drives and have created one in the PowerEdges Virtual Drive Manager. As that did not work at first, I removed the RAID and tried to install on a single drive, with the same results.

As a side note, starting the installation process seems to overwrite the RAID configuration somehow, as the first hard drive would always be detected as degraded after an attempt, which could be fixed by wiping and re-configuring the RAID.

My BIOS Version is 1.10 2.9.0.

Is this hardware just too old for the OS and I need to downgrade to an older version or is it completely impossible to install Ubuntu on it (Dell website said it should work, tho it did not specify the version) or am I doing something completely wrong?

I do not have much experience with server setup and would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
So after giving this another few tries, it suddenly worked pretty smoothly. I am not 100% certain, but I think the only difference in what I did was, that I explicitly selected to start in UEFI Mode in the boot menu this time, otherwise nothing was different. The RAID controller still thinks the RAID is degraded tho, maybe there's an actual fault in the hard drive? Pretty unlikely but still possible, guess I'm gonna check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the ISO (and copying to USB) again.  It sounds like something might be messed up on the install media.  You could also try the existing media on a different system to see if the problem follows you.